# XML or SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I am working on Application which have several connection through Network Share. Basically Application is based on Doctor Clinic. I have tried with XML. But it give me seriously nightmare. with multi processes. So can any one suggest me good way to save datas with multi threading process.

Comment: So you have issues because multiple clients attempt to perform operations on a single file over a network share? - Then yes, this is one of the problems a database *server* mitigates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes use SQL Server, could probably get away with SQL Server Express. However if this is a Doctor Clinic you should invest some time in looking into security of your records as well, something XML doesn't readily provide.

Comment: Hey, I have just convert my Application from XML To SQL but I am unable to access *.mdf file from other PC (Network Sharing) It give not support error! What else I supposed to do next!

Comment: You don't `access` the MDF. You connect to the server instance, that manages the MDF for you.

Comment: Any url related that? I am bit confused here!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C